# Possibility to get battery info (audio) on top of active phone call

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm planning to have my secondary smartphone as recording instrument via a phone call (2G, not voip)

Means, my primary smartphone will call secondary one. And this secondary phone will be left on active call, so i could hear it's surrounding conversations through my primary phone

But the problem is, i couldn't find a way to know it's battery information. I was hoping there is an app i could install on secondary phone, which will tell receiver on other end of call (text to speech) how much battery left there (i.e saying "battery now 20%")

Since there is none (probably because of very limited use cases), me and my friend plan to make one. Tried all day long figure out on android studio documentation, seem no luck. Any suggestion? or it's simply impossible?

(Sorry for bad english. Hopefully can be understood properly)

Comment: `BatteryManager` is probably what you're looking for. See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.